# Install latest python version in Alpine Linux

Tags: python, docker, alpine-linux

I'm creating a docker image and I've installed alpine:3.10 as OS. However when I try to install python I get Python 3.7.10,  and some of my dependencies require python version >=3.9.

I've tried to install the latest python version throught `apk add --no-cache python3=3.10.2-r0` but it does not work. I get the error:

```
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.10/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.10/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
ERROR: unable to select packages:
  python3-3.7.10-r0:
    breaks: world[python3=3.10.2-r0]
```

I would like to know if is possible install the latest python version in Alpine Linux, thanks in advance.

Comment: You could use a Docker alpine-python container as starting image, see https://hub.docker.com/_/python. Or if you want to build it yourself, you could follow the steps which are done in those Dockerfiles, see for example https://github.com/docker-library/python/blob/0047f00c0967161e731c9bab7d50fd95c7c09d46/3.11-rc/alpine3.15/Dockerfile

Comment: You can always download python from official page (https://www.python.org/) and compile it yourself. Or, use anaconda (https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual) which I would highly recommend.

Comment: You are on a **really old** version of Alpine, as it was release [two and a half year ago](https://alpinelinux.org/posts/Alpine-3.10.0-released.html). Get yourself a recent version of Alpine (i.e., the latest `alpine:3:15`) and you will have python 3.9.7-r4. If you want python 3.10 you can hop on the `alpine:edge` although not recommended for production use.